# Looking for a date format in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have the following date in this format:

```
fecha='2018-03-03T00:00:00.000Z'
```

I have checked out in the pandas doc the different formats that can be applied to a date, however I cannot find a format that somehow beautifies it to obtain this output:

```
March-18
```

As much as I get to is :

```
fecha_fto=(pd.to_datetime(fecha[0:10])).strftime('%m-%Y')
```

That outputs

```
03-2018
```

Is there anyway the date could get formmated somehow to obtain the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handy site - http://strftime.org/

Use `'%B-%y'`

```
pd.to_datetime('2018-03-03T00:00:00.000Z').strftime('%B-%y')

'March-18'
```